# .Net Core Response Redirect Another View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to security of some pages. These were the methods I used mvc 5 and before.

```
@{
   if(ViewBag.SessionId == null)
   {
      Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");
   }
}
```

But this way doesn't way now.I could not find a solution in my research. .What should I do now ?

Comment: You should do it on the controller level

Answer (score 2):

You can replace it by:

```
@{ 
    if (ViewBag.SessionId == null)
    {
        Context.Response.Redirect(Url.Content("~/Home/Index"));
    }
}
```

As Shyju noted, probably it is better to handle such redirection on the controller or even filter level. Another improvement could be a replacement `Url.Content("~/Home/Index")` to `Url.Action("Index", "Home")` in case when `~/Home/Index` points to the `HomeController.Index` action.